# Nuxt3 useFetch sends request only once

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

const loadPost = () => {
  console.log('load')
  const { data, pending, error, refresh } = useFetch(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        title: 'foo',
        body: 'bar',
        userId: 1,
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
  console.log(data)
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="max-w-xs space-y-4 mx-auto mt-4">
      <button @click.prevent="loadPost">Load post</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]

[image]

After clicking on the load button, I see every time the request is processed through the console log, but I do not see a new request in the network chrome devtools, I need to receive a response from the server every time, how can I do this?

Note: If I use a regular `fetch()`, then the request is sent every time, as it should be

my nuxt version - 3.0.0-rc.1

Answer (score 8):

Thanks! Solved by adding param `initialCache: false`

```
useFetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2?delay=1', { initialCache: false })
```

Comment: Still, probably not a good way to call a lifecycle for that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to re-fetch the data, use the [`refresh()` method returned from `useFetch()`](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch#return-values):

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2?delay=1')

const loadPost = () => {
  refresh()
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-reload-data-with-usefetch?file=components%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: @Ifaruki It looks like you can use it with or without `await` because [Nuxt copies the async data fields into the returned `Promise` object](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/blob/46c656c4b85c3622b99a7c4f6a01f5b11c830be6/packages/nuxt/src/app/composables/asyncData.ts#L170). If the user needs to use the data synchronously in `script setup`, then the `await` would be needed. However, I believe another implication of using top-level `await` in `script setup` is the component becomes an *async component*, requiring a `<Suspense>` to render it. I'll verify.

Comment: It seems `<Suspense>` isn't explicitly needed in Nuxt, which means it's automatically wrapping the root component with `<Suspense>`. Top-level await without `<Suspense>` [wouldn't work in plain Vue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-top-level-await?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue,src%2FApp.vue).

Answer (score 3):

Watch out! you need a key.  In you don't provide one, will generate it from the URL.  This might not get you the result you expect.  Generate a different key if the data will change.

Here is in the [docs](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch)

Options (from useAsyncData):
key: a unique key to ensure that data fetching can be properly de-duplicated across requests, **if not provided, it will be generated based on the url and fetch options.**

Comment: its works. but you must be sure write as "string" type

Answer (score 0):

refresh/execute: a function that can be used to refresh the data returned by the handler function.
By default, Nuxt waits until a refresh is finished before it can be executed again.

```
const loadPost = async () => {
  console.log('load')
  const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        title: 'foo',
        body: 'bar',
        userId: 1,
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
  refresh();
  console.log(data)
}
```